# error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found

Tags: c#, .net, docker, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

in my gitlab-ci.yml i want a C# project to be checked by sonarqube(community edition)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKTTh.png)

at the build-stage i get this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTIB3.png)

The .csproj file explicitly asks for .Net Framework Version 4.7.2.

As i have little knowlege i wonder if i may add a line in my gitlab-ci.yml to install the missing version befor the build process, like i tried in line 17, which failed.

Second thought would be that the project i want to be analysed is just to old and .NetFramework v.4.7.2 is outdated/not included in .Net SDK v.8 .

Anyways, my question is, what needs to be done to continue at this stage and to be able to analyse the C# project.

I have like 1 month of experience. gitlab and sonarqube are hosted on a local server as docker containers.

I did some research which led to confusion.

Edit: 19.10.23 ; 12:00
updated gitlab.yml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5iT.png

Edit: 23.1023 ; 12:21
added .csproj file i am using for this project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{BEBB4651-1EE2-415E-BEA5-3FC0E271BBFC}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>HT10KokoCom</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>HT10KokoCom</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>htx 32x32.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Management" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="AES128Service.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CassemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CcalibData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Ccsv.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CgrafElements.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Ckoko1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ClassCommand.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CprotokollHtxKoko.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="htx 32x32.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="htx2 32x32.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you try to install the required .NET version on the machine that's running the pipeline? It clearly states, that the container is missing this version of .NET.

You tried to install the runtime (in your script at line 17). Please try to install the SDK version of it.

Comment: Hi Doern,
My machine running the pipeline runs on OpenMediaVault which is debian. I installed .Net SDK v.7 and tried Mono. In my gitlab.yml i added aspnetcore-runtime-7.0
The same error persists.

Comment: Could you please paste the content of the .csproj-file that references this .Net Framework version?

Comment: I added the .csproj file. I hope it makes sense to you, it does not make sense to me though.

Comment: This csproj file indicates it is old .net framework project, which is not the same as new .net at all. This will most likely only build on windows machines, it is not cross platform like new .net is.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.7.2 isn't supported on the .NET SDK image, you need the
[.NET Framework SDK image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk). In your case you would need at least `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2` although the 4.8 and 4.8.1 tags also support building that .NET version. I personally recommend using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8` as it is supported on more versions of windows hosts.